# Bluehost remote access database

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing this error to connect with database of bluehost server:

> Warning: mysql_connect(): No connection could be made because the
>   target machine actively refused it. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\besttour\inc\db_con.inc2.php on line 9

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Here is the code for that

```
   ini_set('display_errors',1);

   $Server = "182.185.168.229";
   $User = "username";
   $Password = "password";
   $DB = "databasename";
   $DomainName = "http://besttours.com.sg/";    
   $link = mysql_connect($Server, $User, $Password) or die(mysql_error());
   if($link)
      echo "connected to live database";
   mysql_select_db($DB, $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
     // Define connection info
     $dbhost = ip;
     $dbuser = username;
     $dbpass = password;
     $dbname = databseName;
     $dbport = databasePort;

     // create the connection and see if it connects or fails
     $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname, $dbport);
     if ($conn->connect_errno) 
         {
             echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
         }

     // define your query
     $query = " INSERT QUERY HERE";

     // then execute the query and save the result set
     if ($result = $conn->query($query)) 
         {
           //leave this here
         }
```

**NOTE:** Defining your variables at the top of the file is very dangerous. It allows anyone to see your connection information. You want to put the connection info in a PHP file outside the root of your web server / website root.

**Also to note:** I see you are using mysql_connect which has been deprecated. Any new version of PHP installed will not accept the command. [Link to that here.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) Please use the newer MySQLi. [Which can be found here.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 0):

Its not a code issue its a blue host setting issue,  it usually supports only connection from its local host, but you can override this in your cpanel, simply go to ypu cpanel, database section, and choose remote mysql.
you can add your public ip address. If you do not know what is your public ip simply go to http://ip.w69b.com/.